# Root users and mysql: `sudo mysql` vs `/root/.my.cnf`

Tags: mysql, sudo, root, users

I have a `/root/.my.cnf` file which stores the mysql root user's password:

```
[client]
password = "my password"
```

When I log in as system root and enter mysql, I get a passwordless login:

```
myuser@local:$ sudo su
root@local:$ mysql
mysql>
```

But when I try to do the same just using sudo, I get access denied:

```
myuser@local:$ sudo mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How can I get `sudo mysql` to log me in as the mysql root user, without entering a password?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sudo -i mysql` should also work - That should run mysql under a fresh interactive shell.

Answer (score 2):

If you are locked down and the only command you can enter as sudo is mysqldump (non-interactive) you might be looking to add the .my.cnf option by the --defaults-file param.

Comment: This won't work unless you have read permissions on the root my.cnf file. It you don't, it fails with "Could not open required defaults file: /root/.my.cnf
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted".

Answer (score 1):

The command `sudo su -c "mysql"` will have the desired effect.